# Reading text file contents into a list

Tags: python, csv, file-io, file-import

I have a text file containing:

```
1:PAPER TOWNS,TOMORROWLAND
2:ENTOURAGE,JUPITER ASCENDING
```

and I'm planning to read them into a list which outputs:

```
[[1,'PAPERTOWNS','TOMORROWLAND'],[2,'ENTOURAGE','JUPITERASCENDING']]
```

I have written:

```
def read_file():
    fileName = "testing.txt"
    testFile = open(fileName)
    table = []

    for line in testFile:
        contents = line.strip().split(':')
        contents[0] = int(contents[0])
        contents[1] = contents[1].replace(' ','')
        table.append(contents)
    print(table)
```

I almost managed to get the output i wanted but i couldn't figure out a way to separate the strings from:

```
[[1,'PAPERTOWNS,TOMORROWLAND'],[2,'ENTOURAGE,JUPITERASCENDING']]
```

to

```
[[1,'PAPERTOWNS','TOMORROWLAND'],[2,'ENTOURAGE','JUPITERASCENDING']]
```

Comment: Your file is like a CSV file, just the separator character can be colon or comma, so we use a regex in pandas. The result is a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the second element by comma.

**Demo**

```
def read_file():
    fileName = "testing.txt"
    testFile = open(fileName)
    table = []

    for line in testFile:
        contents = line.strip().split(':')
        table.append([int(contents[0])] + contents[1].split(","))
    print(table)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 'PAPER TOWNS', 'TOMORROWLAND'], [2, 'ENTOURAGE', 'JUPITER ASCENDING']]
```

**Using Regex:**

```
import re
def read_file():
    fileName = "testing.txt"
    testFile = open(fileName)
    table = []

    for line in testFile:
        contents = re.split("[,:]+", line.strip())
        table.append(contents)
    print(table)
```

**Output:**

```
[['1', 'PAPER TOWNS', 'TOMORROWLAND'], ['2', 'ENTOURAGE', 'JUPITER ASCENDING']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one-liner with pandas. Your file is like a CSV file, just the separator character can be colon or comma, so we use a regex:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None, sep=r'[:,]')
```

Comment: (Ignore the ParserWarning or suppress it with a `try...except ParserWarning`)

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string by multiple delimiters :

```
import re
print([[int(re.split(':|,', line.strip())[0])]+re.split(':|,', line.strip())[1:] for line in open('text_file','r')])
```

output:

```
[[1, 'PAPER TOWNS', 'TOMORROWLAND'], [2, 'ENTOURAGE', 'JUPITER ASCENDING']]
```